# Error creating bean, can't inject a new LinkedBlockingQueue as a constructor to ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container, javabeans

I'm trying to create a ThreadPoolExecutor bean which needs to be passed as a property to a number of other beans.

I have defined the following, but I'm encountering an odd error creating the LinkedBlockingQueue (seen below).

```
<bean name="moduleExecutorService" class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor">
    <constructor-arg value="1" />   <!-- Minimun # of threads in pool -->
    <constructor-arg value="20" />  <!-- Maximum # of threads in pool (pool is a caching pool that will only keep open those necessary) -->
    <constructor-arg value="60" />  <!-- Shutdown unused threads after this TimeUnit -->
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit" factory-method="valueOf">
            <constructor-arg value="SECONDS" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue"><bean class="java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue" /></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**Error:**

```
446  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate  - Cannot create copy of Collection type [java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue] - injecting original Collection as-is
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue
```

Comment: Try without the type="..." on the constructor-arg, or try specifying type="java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure why this message shows up. In the end it's only a `DEBUG` message and it should not prevent you from bringing up your application. Alternatively, you could use a `FactoryBean` instead that instantiates `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
public class ThreadPoolExecutorFactory implements FactoryBean 
{
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();   
    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
    private int corePoolSize;
    private int maximumPoolSize;
    private long keepAliveTime;
    private TimeUnit unit;

    public Object getObject() 
    {
        lock.lock();
        if (executor == null)
            executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize,
                    keepAliveTime, unit, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        lock.unlock();
        return executor;
    }

    public Class getObjectType() 
    {
        return ThreadPoolExecutor.class;
    }

    public boolean isSingleton()    
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your application context you'd then create the bean like this:

```
<bean name="moduleExecutorService" class="ThreadPoolExecutorFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="1" /> 
    <constructor-arg value="20" /> 
    <constructor-arg value="60" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit" factory-method="valueOf">
            <constructor-arg value="SECONDS" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```